# what is the difference between using findViewById() and using directly the id?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new with android and kotlin, so sorry if it's a too basic question 
but I don't see the difference between this

```
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.done_button).setOnClickListener { changeNickname() }
```

and this`done_button.setOnClickListener { changeNickname() }`

Comment: I am surprised to see the question had been closed without and answer apparently noone knows whats going on

Answer (score 0):

if you will use `done_button` more one time it will be to much writing each time add this

`findViewById<Button>(R.id.done_button)`

in general your code have to be smallest and readable 
please read more about the clean code  .